# Pls explain the media architecture of ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can anyone explain the Media Architecture provided in the following link?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/MediaArchitecture

I want the description of the diagram shown below:

[image]

Comment: This may have already changed.
--- You should direct your question to the developers. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install 'Need Help?' (at bottom of page) --- *Questions about these installation instructions are still suitable for this forum.*

Comment: The diagram on the bottom of the page is an UML-diagram of the Media Architecure of the Ubuntu touch. What did you exactly want to know?

Comment: I didn't understand the terms described in the diagram. Eg:glibc, bionic ...etc. Actually i want to know how this diagram related to working of ubuntu touch and I need the working description also. If you have more architecture diagrams of ubuntu touch, pls give me that too.

Comment: Are you a developer? If not, then these things wont matter to you anyway. And if you are a developer then you should know what this means already.